# How can I delete a selected DataGridView row from the database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a Windows Forms form with `DataGridView`. The `DataGridView` has `DataGridViewButtonColumn`, and I have a database (id with autoincrement).

I can delete it from `DataGridView`.

```
private void dgv_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
   if (e.ColumnIndex == Delete.Index) {
      dgv.Rows.Remove(dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
   }
}
```

How can I delete it from the database?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What have you tryed? Are you using an OR Mapper?

Comment: Are you using a datatable as the DataSource?  Then remove from table.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your database's unique id as commandArgument to your cell button and when you call the delete command simply pass that id to remove that record from database.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnCellDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument = "<%# Eval("DB_ID")%>" Text="Delete Row" />
```

Get value in backend:

```
var item = (Button)e.Row.DataItem;
var dbID  = item.CommandArgument.ToStrng();
```

and you can perform database delete on your button click event also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an SQL query to delete it from the database. Get a datagridview selected items and run a delete query like this:

```
int id= this.dataGridView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;

con.Open();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
cmd.CommandText = "delete from data where id=@id";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I don't know which method are you using but you can delete it with LINQ like this:

```
Product deleteProduct = northWind.Products.First(u => u.ProductID == id);

northWind.Products.DeleteOnSubmit(deleteProduct);
```